# Replacing For loop with multiple iterator with Table

Tags: list-manipulation, map, iterators

I have written code for calculating cristofell symbol using for loop with 3 iterators for each coordinate

```
A = {
   {1, 0, 0},
   {0, r^2, 0},
   {0, 0, 1}
  } ;
Kor[n_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {(r), n == 1},
   {(\[Theta]), n == 2},
   {(z), n == 3}
  } 
ChristoffelSymbol1[i_, j_, k_] := 
 1/2 (-D[A[[i, j]], Korr[k]] + D[A[[j, k]], Korr[i]] + 
    D[A[[k, i]], Korr[j]])
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,
    For[j = 1, j < 4, j++,
        For[k = 1, k < 4, k++,

            Print[Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], i, j, k], " = ", 
    ChristoffelSymbol1[i, j, k]]

              ]
        ]
    ]
```

I was wandering if I could use `Map`/`Table` to do the same without changing the functions too much.
As far as I could tell I need to make the `Piecewise` function return symbols for `i, j, k` when they are entered instead of number so I dont get an error when I do 
`ChristoffelSymbol1[1,j,k]` and (this I don't know how) somehow define what happens when I try to access the matrix `A` with `A[[1,j]]` for example , so it doesn't give me `"expression j cannot be used as a part specification"` and leave it in symbolic notation so it can be used when `j` iterators start.

Comment: if you actually want to `Print` like that you would use `Do`.  I dont see why you would have the part issue you are imagining -- try it.   I wouldn't bother with that `Piecewise` by the way , just do `Kor[1]=r;Kor[2]=theta;Kor[3]=z` or do `Kor={r,theta,z}` and reference it as a list.

Comment: You can use for example [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html?q=Tuples) and then `Map` function over the obtained list. However, it is unclear from your question what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want a table of {Symbol,value} pairs outputted in 1 cell,but for the symbol to keep the formatting from print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\[CapitalGamma]ddd[i_, j_, k_] := 
 1/2 (-D[A[[i, j]], Kor[[k]]] + D[A[[j, k]], Kor[[i]]] + 
    D[A[[k, i]], Kor[[j]]])

A = DiagonalMatrix[{1, r^2, 1}]
Kor = {r, \[Theta], z}

Table[{Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], i, j, k], \[CapitalGamma]ddd[i, j, 
    k]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
 A = {
  {1, 0, 0},
  {0, r^2, 0},
  {0, 0, 1}
 } ;  B = {
  {1, 0, 0},
  {0, 1/r^2, 0},
  {0, 0, 1}
 }; 
Kor[n_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {(r), n == 1},
   {(\[Theta]), n == 2},
   {(z), n == 3}
  } 
ChristoffelSymbol1[i_, j_, k_] := 
 1/2 (-D[A[[i, j]], Kor[k]] + D[A[[j, k]], Kor[i]] + 
    D[A[[k, i]], Kor[j]])
ChristoffelSymbol2[i_, j_, m_] := 
 Sum[B[[k, m]] ChristoffelSymbol1[i, j, k], {k, 1, 3}]
TableForm[
 Table[{Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], i, j, k], 
   ChristoffelSymbol1[i, j, k]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 3}]]
TableForm[
 Table[{Subscript[Superscript[\[CapitalGamma], m], i, j], 
   ChristoffelSymbol2[i, j, m]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}, {m, 1, 3}]]
```

When i tried to replace `For` with `Table` i just copied the iterators,they were going from 1-4 in the loop  and the marix is 3x3 so it bugged out :p